# SQL Query in PHP date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, between

I'have a problem in my Sql query in PHP:

If I do :

```
$result = mssql_query("SELECT xx FROM x JOIN x ON x WHERE x = '".$var1."' 
AND x BETWEEN '20150401 00:00:00' AND '20150401 23:59:59' ")
```

That's work

But if I do :

```
$day=date("d/m/Y",time());
$exploDate = explode("/", $day);
$dateStart = $exploDate[2].$exploDate[1].$exploDate[0]." 00:00:00";
$dateEnd = $exploDate[2].$exploDate[1].$exploDate[0]." 23:59:59";
$result = mssql_query("SELECT xx FROM x JOIN x ON x WHERE x = '".$var1."' 
AND x BETWEEN '".$dateStart."' AND '".$dateEnd."' ")
```

That's doesn't work !

I don't understand why 
Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really mean "FROM x JOIN x"? And why the name mssql_query if it's MySQL - very confusing.

Comment: Echo out or var_dump your variables, one or more of them probably isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Try using `echo $dateStart` and `echo $dateEnd` before calling your query to see if the values you're entering are correct.

Answer (score 2):

[KISS Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

```
date('Y-m-d 00:00:00')."' AND '". date('Y-m-d 23:59:59')
```

or

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
// ...
... "BETWEEN '" . $today . " 00:00:00' AND '" . $today . " 23:59:59'"
```

Comment: Would that work with the date formatting from the first query? It seems his original format has the year, month and day jammed together with no separation.

Comment: there is a manual for date() function. You can use `date("Ymd")` as well as - once you read manual - even something to produce "2015 is a year of lovers!" if you want: `echo date('Y \Y\e\a\r \o\f \l\o\v\e\r\s');`.